# Using rand() in header file

Tags: c++

I want to populate an array with three different random integers.

```
int itemA[3] = {rand() % 20 + 1, rand() % 20 + 1, rand() % 20 + 1};
```

Currently I can only seed the random integer if it is in the main. Can someone tell me how to seed it in the header file where my array is?

From what I've found so far, I think I need srand ( time(0) ) in there, but it only does what I want it to do if it is in the main.

Comment: FWIW, it is a really bad idea to define a variable in a header file unless it is marked `inline`.

Comment: Why do you have an array (declaration?) in your header file?

Comment: @jjramsey It's a common mistake. Specially since it looks like it works at first in simple projects, where only 1 translation unit includes the header.

Comment: You can implement a (private) _Singleton_ to seed a random engine once.

Comment: Looks like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me.

Comment: static struct InitRand
{
    InitRand() { srand(time(0)); }
} initRand;  
int itemA[3] = {rand() % 20 + 1, rand() % 20 + 1, rand() % 20 + 1};

Comment: As a sidenote, in C++ you don't use `rand()` but the C++ random generators instead (from `#include <random>`). They are better quality and don't have global state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a surprisingly deep and important question—so much so that it’s mentioned in my profile.  The answer is simple: you **don’t** do this in the header, even though inline variables make it possible to do so.  The reason is important: as **global** state, the seed must be set **once** (consider that, if multiple headers each set the seed with `time(0)` before drawing their “random” numbers, they would typically all get the same results).

There are corollaries to this: since the main program is the only part that (by definition) knows the **user’s** intentions, it should perform such initialization; for example, the user might wish to reproduce previous results by specifying a seed via a command-line option.  Even if your program doesn’t support such features (yet), you already have to have a **source** file to contain `main`, so you might as well seed the RNG there.

You might object that you’re not writing `main`, and perhaps that you have no source files at all.  However, that just means that you’re writing a (perhaps header-only) **library**, which immediately implies that for **composability** you mustn’t arrogate the responsibility for initialization ([what if more than one library did?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413).

The same logic applies to any other **process-global** parameters like the current working directory or environment variables.  It’s fine for libraries (and internal header files, treating them as miniature libraries) to provide functions to **help** `main` manipulate such things (*e.g.*, to collect entropy for the seed or add elements to `PATH`-like environment variables), but they should never take such actions on their own.